# Decoding special characters into HTML characters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have been searching the web for a javascript function that turns something like this:

```
Hi.&amp;nbsp; I will show &lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;.
```

Into this:

```
Hi.&nbsp; I will show <span style="font-weight: bold;">HTML</span>.
```

I am using this method:

```
htmlDecode: function (input) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

And it works the first time.  But if I try it again, on text like this:

```
Hi.&nbsp; I will show <span style="font-weight: bold;">HTML</span>
```

It strips out all the html and just leaves me with:

Hi. I will show HTML.

I only want the method to change this:

```
Hi.&amp;nbsp; I will show &lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;.
```

Into this:

```
Hi.&nbsp; I will show <span style="font-weight: bold;">HTML</span>.
```

I don't want it to totally strip out the HTML.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Why then do you call it a second time on the result of the first call? Just call it once only?

Comment: @trincot I know but this function is fired whenever text is saved to the backend.  So I guess thought it would be ok on everyting.  But how would I tell it not to fire on text that is already ok?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the parsed result contains DOM elements. If so, then it means the decoding went one step too far, and the original value should be returned:

```js
function htmlDecode (input) {
    let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
    let body = doc.querySelector("body");
    return body.children.length ? input : body.textContent;
}

let s = 'Hi.&amp;nbsp; I will show &lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;.';
s = htmlDecode(s);
console.log(s); // decoded
s = htmlDecode(s); // apply on the result...
console.log(s); // ... no change

s = htmlDecode("Hi.&nbsp; This is normal text.");
console.log(s);
```

### An additional check

Another assumption could be that it should be possible to decode the result of a first decoding and get a different result again. If it produces twice the same result, then the original input should be returned.

```js
function htmlDecode (input) {
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(input, "text/html");
    let { textContent, children } = doc.querySelector("body");
    if (children.length) return input;
    doc = parser.parseFromString(textContent, "text/html");
    if (doc.querySelector("body").textContent === textContent) return input;
    return textContent;
}

let s = 'Hi.&amp;nbsp; I will show &lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;.';
s = htmlDecode(s);
console.log(s); // decoded
s = htmlDecode(s); // apply on the result...
console.log(s); // ... no change

s = "Hi.&amp;nbsp; This is normal text.";
s = htmlDecode(s);
console.log(s); // decoded
s = htmlDecode(s); // apply on the result...
console.log(s); // ... no change
```

Comment: Hi! This is working a lot better, but I noticed if I have text like this: `Hi.&nbsp; This is normal text.`, and then I run that function above, it will be a `&amp` in front of the `&nbsp;` so that the text then looks like this: `Hi.&amp;nbsp; This is normal text.`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. If you pass "Hi.&nbsp; This is normal text." as argument to this function, the `&nbsp;` will be replaced with a non breaking space, so that you get "Hi. This is normal text.". I have added this case to my snippet so you can see it run.

Comment: But it is true that if you decode "Hi.&amp;nbsp; This is normal text." and then decode the result of that, it will still resolve entities further. The thing is: you cannot know whether the original string was really "Hi.&amp;nbsp; This is normal text." or ""Hi.&nbsp; This is normal text.". Both could be true. Without further information, it is impossible to distinguish both cases. It could even be that the original text was "Hi.&amp;amp;nbsp; This is normal text." ... etc

Comment: I extended my answer with another heuristic, so to capture this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div, set it's `innerHTML`, and then retrieve it's `innerText`.

```js
function htmlDecode(text) {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = text
  return div.innerText
}

console.log(htmlDecode('Hi.&amp;nbsp; I will show &lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;.'))
```

Comment: This will allow for arbitrary code execution. DOMParser is probably a better idea

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks!  That's exactly why I'm using DOMParser. :)